# CSS content with wrong sybmol

Tags: javascript, css, unicode

I'm using materialize.css inside it I found selector

```
.mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down:before {
  content: "\e894";
}
```

It should show arrow but as a result I'm getting a square. If I change it to `\25BC` it works. But what's a problem with this library?  I have downloaded it [here](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html).

Comment: If you get a square, the font doesn't have that glyph.

Comment: U+E894 is inside the [PUA (private use area) of Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). It's for custom font glyphs, and as such you shouldn't expect it to be available to everyone.

Comment: What should I change for correct work, without changing content?

Comment: @jenius What about [`\2193`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2193/index.htm)?

Comment: I've just seen your edits. Are you sure you've added the appropriate `<link>` and `<script>` tags for materialize's css and js?

Comment: like this <style>
        <%@include file="../../resources/materialize/css/materialize.css"%>
    </style>  and js alomost the same way

Comment: I've do it. I obtain all necessary components

Comment: Why are you including the files inline? Use appropriate `<link>` and `<script>` tags that refer to external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the arrow, \e894 is a character not widely supported by many fonts.

Normally I would say take this up with materialize, however, the intended use-case is to use the font provided by them, I would believe.

Comment: I guess when I included their css, I've already used their font, Isn't it?

Comment: No, their font is a different file you need to include on your own, if you're not using their entire system.

Comment: Download the font file and make sure their css is referencing it properly in the @font-face declaration.

Comment: Also, when using the icon `content: '\e894'`, make sure that you've also included the icon-font name using the font-family rule. For example: `my-icon:before { content: '\e894'; font-family: 'my-icons'; }`